# Advantages of a back quiver

Tags: gear, archery

It seems like the back quiver has only disadvantages compared to a bow or side quiver. Yet many archers - including Byron Ferguson - choose to go with them.

What advantages (besides looking awesome) does a back quiver have?

Comment: I don't think there are any. If you jump, arrows pop out. If you are going through brush, arrows get hung up. At least with a side quiver you can put your hand over the arrows or grab them before they get hung up on something. Plus a side quiver gives better faster access to your arrows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Bow Quiver vs. Back Quiver

- A bag with a shoulder strap is super simple to dream up and create whereas a workable bow quiver is much harder to build. Of course this only matters if you are making it or don't have access to modern building methods.
- You can store more arrows in a back quiver than a bow quiver. This is a matter of simple real estate. You have more space on your back to store arrows than on the side of your bow.

  ---

#### Side/Hip Quiver vs. Back Quiver

- IMO it is **a more natural and fluid motion** to reach over your shoulder to grab the arrow, nock the arrow, and place it on arrow rest. My artistic skills are limited but you can picture in your mind **a fluid single arc of motion**. In contrast with **a hip quiver where the arrows point back** you need to pull back, point the arrow forward, nock the arrow, and then place it on the arrow rest. In your mind you can see that is **more of an open-V motion or a big arm circle**. When the **hip quiver is pointing forward you need to spin the arrow (palm towards body) in your fingers or a big diagonal up and back (palm away from body)** like a sword salute at a wedding after the draw before nocking the arrow. The spin can be fancy/pretty but it is easier to drop the arrow.
- It seems to me that a hip quiver with the arrows pointing forward would be inconvenient because the arrows would be hitting things and generally getting in the way. Unless you're wearing a backpack arrows in a back quiver are out of the way.

  ---

Bow quiver:

[image: bow quiver]

Side/hip quiver pointing back:

[image: hip quiver pointing back]

Side/hip quiver pointing forward:

[image: hip quiver pointing forward]

Back quiver:

[image: Back quiver]